# Rolling time window

Tags: c#, stack, queue

I have a system where a user may do a request 3 times within a given timeframe. How do I program that in C#?

I know I could just give User 3 properties (`DateTime1`, `DateTime2`, `DateTime3`), and check on those, but that feels wrong. Is there a smarter way to do it? I was also thinking about using a stack or queue, but can't figure out how.

It would be nice if both the timeframe and request-limit could be changed ad-hoc (so no individual properties).

#### Example:

Window is 60 minutes:
[image: Example]
User 1 have used up the timeframe limit, and is denied access.
User 2 have not used up the limit, so is accepted.

The timeframe is, as mentioned, rolling.

Comment: I think we need more details to be able to answer your question. Plus, what have you tried?

Comment: What data does the user request?

Comment: Added clearification.
What data is trying to be accessed is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own `RollingTimeWindow` class which records the latest successful requests and only performs the request if the timing allows it.

You can test it using this code. Press ENTER to try to perform a request, it will only get executed if the time window allows it.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    //Only allow 3 requests in a time window of 10 seconds.
    var r = new RollingTimeWindow(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () => Console.WriteLine("Executed."));
    while (true) {
        Console.ReadLine(); //wait for press on Enter
        r.PerformRequest();
    }
}
```

This is a simple code to get you started to handle your rolling time window:

```cs
public class RollingTimeWindow {
    private Queue<DateTime> _latestRequests = new Queue<DateTime>();
    private readonly int _maxNumberOfRequests;
    private readonly TimeSpan _windowSize;
    private Action _action;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new RollingTimeWindow performing requests if allowed by the time frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maximumNumberOfRequests">Number of requests allowed in the window size</param>
    /// <param name="windowSize">Rolling window size</param>
    /// <param name="requestAction">Action to invoke when the request must be performed</param>
    public RollingTimeWindow(int maximumNumberOfRequests, TimeSpan windowSize, Action requestAction = default) {
        _action = requestAction;
        _maxNumberOfRequests = maximumNumberOfRequests;
        if (_maxNumberOfRequests < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(maximumNumberOfRequests));
        }
        _windowSize = windowSize;
    }

    //Returns true if the request would be allowed, else false (NOT threadsafe)
    public bool IsRequestAllowed() {
        CleanQueue(DateTime.Now);
        return _latestRequests.Count < _maxNumberOfRequests;
    }

    //Returns true if the request was performed, else false.
    public bool PerformRequest() {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        CleanQueue(now);
        if (_latestRequests.Count < _maxNumberOfRequests) {
            _latestRequests.Enqueue(now);
            _action(); //perform the actual request
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; //request not allowed
        }
    }

    private void CleanQueue(DateTime now) {
        //Cleans all requests older than the window size
        while (_latestRequests.Count > 0 && _latestRequests.Peek() < now - _windowSize) {
            _latestRequests.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is not thread-safe, and that it could also be implemented with `Timer` objects to automatically dequeue older values.

Comment: That is a pretty nice implementation! I will look into it and see if it works in my system. If it does I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking for my system, it works flawlesly.